# Efficient large sparse block compressed linear equation in C++

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, solver, algebra

everyone.
I have little experience about linear algebra equation solver.
But now, I need to solve the large sparse block compressed linear equation.
i.e., `Ax=b`.

Matrix `A` is composed of sub-blocks whose size is `(nb,nb)`. and size of `A` is `(N,N)` subblocks.
Then the real size of matrix `A` is `(nb*N,nb*N)`.

There are only few sub-blocks exists. And `A` is diagonal dominant.

I have tried Eigen's built-in slovers. i.e., SimplicialLLT and BiCGSTAB, the first is slow while the second cannot converge.

Then I tried third-party solvers of Eigen with Intel MKL, i.e., PardisoLLT 、PardisoLDLT and PardisoLU. They were slow too.

Finally, I tried third-party solvers of Eigen with SuiteSparse, i.e., CHOLMOD and SPQR. The first is slow while the second gave the same value of input, it seems that it didn't work.

I think maybe it is because that I used the solvers in wrong way that I didn't take advantage of feature "block compress" and thus triggered a lot of useless computing.

Could anyone give me some advices?

Comment: how big is N ? When you used cholmod did you use GPUs? it's very hard to help without some code or your build environment details

Comment: It can be very big. Currently, I tried with a matrix of size 1200*1200. (i.e., Nb is 12, and N is 100). I just have a gtx 1080 card at present, but I have to use "double" to keep precision. So, maybe gpu is not a good choice.

Comment: I have a SOR iteration solver which is designed for this block-compressed equation. The SOR solver solve this equation for about 1500 times costs about 110 seconds. While The cholmod solver with Eigen interface cost about 330 seconds. But the SOR solver can only use 1 thread which will be slow in big equation case.

Comment: Matrix 1200*1200 is not a big size for sparse matrices. What is its sparsity (nonzero/1200/1200)? The 330sec is only for one call of cholmod?

Comment: thank you, Masud and ztik. I found that my IDE (QtCreator) double the equation solving time because I haven't restart it for more than one week in debugging. When I restart QtCreator, Eigen with SuiteSparse CHOLMOD solver is faster than my current equation solving tool in an equation 12000*12000 (i.e., Nb=12, N=1000).

Comment: And ztik, for current case, there are 1000 sub-blocks, and only about 0.007 (7*1000/(1000*1000)) of the sub-block matrices is filled with elements.

Answer (score 2):

As long as your matrix size doesn't exceed about 5000 rows/columns, using a sparse solver won't bring any reasonable benefits; for such matrices an ordinary dense solver would be good as well, because it doesn't contains "overheads" related to storing and operating sparse structures, such as linked lists or adjacency structures. On the other hand, if your matrix is very large (say, a million or so rows/columns), an iterative solver only would work. I suggest that you visit the following webpage, which contains description of a problem and solution very similar to what you are working with (including solution of systems with sparse matrices having block structure, as well as image processing): http://members.ozemail.com.au/~comecau/CMA_LS_Sparse.htm

Comment: Just in case if you couldn't find a good solver, you may consider the one to which I gave you the reference; it is available as a brochure with CD-ROM enclosed (it will definitely work for very large matrices; the only restriction is the condition ratio of the matrix, ie. the matrix should be reasonably well-conditioned, with the c.r. value not exceeding about 10^4 or 10^5 at most, or the convergence may not be guaranteed): http://members.ozemail.com.au/~comecau/CMA_brochure.htm

Comment: Erwin Kalvelagen: what product do you use, and on what platform ? If you can give a reliable example of such problem and solution, that would be appreciated.